# Convert MediaWiki wikitext format to HTML using command line

Tags: html, linux, command-line, mediawiki, wikitext

I tend to write a good amount of documentation so the MediaWiki format to me is easy for me to understand plus it saves me a lot of time than having to write traditional HTML.  I, however, also write a blog and find that switching from keyboard to mouse all the time to input the correct tags for HTML adds a lot of time.  I'd like to be able to write my articles in Mediawiki syntax and then convert it to HTML for use on my blog.

I've tried Google-ing but must need better nomenclature as surprisingly I haven't been able to find anything.

I use Linux and would prefer to do this from the command line.

Any one have any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: see also [lexers / parsers for (un) structured text documents](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087699/33499) for alternative formats

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looked into this a bit and think that a good route to take here would be to learn to a general markup language like restucturedtext or markdown and then be able to convert from there.  Discovered a program called [pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554609/is-there-any-tools-to-convert-markdown-to-wiki-text-in-other-formats) that can convert either of these to HTML and Mediawiki.  Appreciate the help.

Example:

```
pandoc -f mediawiki -s myfile.mediawiki  -o myfile.html -s
```

Comment: Please don't. [Alternative parsers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) for wikitext are always very fragile, due to how wikitext has (not) been designed.

Comment: I just tried pandoc as a result of this answer for converting mediawiki to tex and HTML and am very pleased with the results. I can't speak for its fragility but if you're just using the basics like headings, lists etc it looks perfectly fine. It plays nicely with other UNIX commands since it supports stdin/stdout IO which is great for pipes.

Comment: Pandoc does not recognize the full wiki markup. Therefore there will be a lot  of articles which cannot be properly parsed. I tried this myself.

Comment: @Waschbaer - if you remember, what kind of mediawiki syntax does it fail on? Readers considering using it may not need unsupported features that are catered mainly for Wikipedia-like use cases.

Comment: pandoc fails to translate templates in wikitext.

Answer (score 14):

The best would be to use MediaWiki parser. The good news is that MediaWiki 1.19 will provide a command line tool just for that!

Disclaimer: I wrote that tool.

The script is `maintenance/parse.php` some usage examples straight from the source code:

Entering text yourself, ending it with Control + D:

```
$ php maintenance/parse.php --title foo
''[[foo]]''^D
<p><i><strong class="selflink">foo</strong></i>
</p>
$
```

The usual file input method:

```
$ echo "'''bold'''" > /tmp/foo.txt
$ php maintenance/parse.php /tmp/foo.txt
<p><b>bold</b>
</p>$
```

And of course piping to stdin:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo | php maintenance/parse.php
<p><b>bold</b>
</p>$
```

*as of today you can get the script from http://svn.wikimedia.org/svnroot/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/maintenance/parse.php and place it in your maintenance directory. It should work with MediaWiki 1.18*

The script will be made available with MediaWiki 1.19.0.

Comment: Actually this is pretty useful, and just what I need.  Appreciate the info Antoine.

Comment: I get the error "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_error() in /scratch4/dhruv/mediawiki-1.20.2/includes/db/DatabaseMysql.php on line 326" when I try to run the above. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Also, why does this tool take in --dbuser and --dbpass?

Comment: @dhruvbird The eval.php script is an old script that has not been migrated to take recognize --dbuser and --dbpass :(   I have filled bug https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/45254 to track this, though that is not that much of a high priority item =)

Comment: I had some permissions problems with CDB files, so the lazy way to get around them was to use `sudo`. Then it worked.

Comment: I wish it didn't generate "edit" hyperlinks that point to nowhere. I guess some regex manipulation can take care of that. I'm happy it generates a table of contents.

Comment: the best would be running a mediawiki instance, so it also has access to templates.

Comment: That is what `maintenance/parse.php` is doing! It requires a MediaWiki instance and has full access to templates, it is just that the interface is a command line utility rather than editing a page with a web browser.
And I think that question triggered me to write the command line tool :]

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) lists tons of MediaWiki parsers that you could try.