# How do I use the Perl Text-MediawikiFormat to convert mediawiki to xhtml?

Tags: html, perl, converters, mediawiki, wikitext

On an Ubuntu platform, I installed the nice little perl script

```
libtext-mediawikiformat-perl - Convert Mediawiki markup into other text formats
```

which is available [on cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~dprice/Text-MediawikiFormat-0.05/lib/Text/MediawikiFormat.pm). I'm not familiar with perl and have no idea how to go about using this library to write a perl script that would convert a mediawiki file to an html file.  e.g. I'd like to just have a script I can run such as

```
./my_convert_script input.wiki > output.html
```

(perhaps also specifying the base url, etc), but have no idea where to start.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Perl library `Text::MediawikiFormat` isn't really intended for stand-alone use but rather as a formatting engine inside a larger application.

The [documentation at CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~dprice/Text-MediawikiFormat-v1.0/lib/Text/MediawikiFormat.pm) does actually show a way how to use this library, and does note that other modules might provide better support for one-off conversions.

You could try this (untested) one-liner

```
perl -MText::MediawikiFormat -e'$/=undef; print Text::MediawikiFormat::format(<>)' input.wiki >output.html
```

although that defies the whole point (and customization abilities) of this module.

I am sure that someone has already come up with a better way to convert single MediaWiki files, so here is a [list of alternative MediaWiki processors](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) on the mediawiki site. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9343931/1521179) coud also be of help.

Other markup languages, such as [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) provide better support for single-file conversions. Markdown is especially well suited for technical documents and mirrors email conventions. (Also, it is used on this site.)

---

The `libfoo-bar-perl` packages in the Ubuntu repositories are precompiled Perl modules. Usually, these would be installed via `cpan` or `cpanm`. While some of these libraries do include scripts, most don't, and aren't meant as stand-alone applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I started with that very SO question and a list of alternative MediaWiki processors, but after trying a handful that didn't work or supported only some subset of mediawiki syntax I figured I better look somewhere else.   (Other answers from that SO aren't useful either since pandoc only goes one way for mediawiki).

Comment: I agree entirely that markdown would be better -- my goal here is to pull all my old content off of my old mediawiki pages and convert it all to markdown for this very reason.  It is surprising that it is not easier to find such mediawiki tools given that it is much older than markdown.

Comment: @cboettig one possible reason is that there is no real way to convert wikitext to markdown. At most one could convert a subset of wikitext to markdown, and that would still be difficult because wikitext is not a defined markup language. Things might be easier now with [Parsoid](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid) which made wikitext parsing more "scientific".

Answer (score 2):

I believe @amon is correct that perl library I reference in the question is not the right tool for the task I proposed.

I ended up using the [mediawiki API](http://www.openwetware.org/api.php) with the action="parse" to convert to HTML using the mediawiki engine, which turned out to be much more reliable than any of the alternative parsers I tried [proposed on the list](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers). (I then used pandoc to convert my html to markdown.)  The mediawiki API handles extraction of categories and other metadata too, and I just had to append the base url to internal image and page links.

Given the page title and base url, I ended up writing this as an R function.

```
wiki_parse <- function(page, baseurl, format="json", ...){
  require(httr)
  action = "parse"
  addr <- paste(baseurl, "/api.php?format=", format, "&action=", action, "&page=", page, sep="")
  config <- c(add_headers("User-Agent" = "rwiki"), ...)
  out <- GET(addr, config=config)
  parsed_content(out)
}
```

Comment: Huge +1 for not reinventing the MediaWiki parser. :)